# How to create News in android App

Tags: android, feed, news-ticker

I am new to Android App development. I am trying to add News to my android application as per the tutorial : http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/ . After adding code following the above tutorial I could see as Items  and Sub Items(numbered) in fragment_main.xml graphic layout. But when I run my code I am unable to see anything as output. I want to achieve this on menu click. How to do this. Please anybody help.

Comment: *I am unable to see anything* => Then what's happening exactly? Check `logcat` output for error, if any!

Comment: It means No Output even after adding the code. I am getting a blank page without any error.

Comment: Have you tried to perform `debugging`?

Comment: Yes, Nothing problem. But still nothing displaying.

Comment: Is there any other approach to achieve this? Please guide me.